# Unique indexes across columns (not a combination of these columns)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, constraints

I have a question: we have a table that has (among other stuff) a couple of IP/port pairs that I would like to be globally unique to avoid crosstalk in streaming binaries that use this configuration.

Assume a table as follows

```
Create table config 
(
    Id serial NOT NULL,
    One_IP text,
    One_Port integer,
    Two_IP text,
    Two_Port integer
);
```

Then I could add constraints

```
   UNIQUE(One_IP, One_Port)
```

and

```
   UNIQUE(Two_IP, Two_Port)
```

This gets me much of the way there. The will be no crosstalk among different rows an each set.

But these are independent of each other – no "One" IP/port pair will repeat and no "Two" IP/Port pair will repeat but I could still have a One IP/Port the same as a two IP/Port (on same or different rows)
Is there a way to create a constraint that combines them? (not a simple 4 column unique)

If I have these rows:

| Id | One_IP | One_Port | Two_Ip | Two_Port |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 239.1.1.12 | 21 | 239.1.1.13 | 21 |
| 2 | 239.1.1.12 | 22 | 239.1.1.13 | 22 |

Then I shouldn't be able to insert any of the following rows ...

| Id | One_IP | One_Port | Two_Ip | Two_Port |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | 239.1.1.12 | 21 | 239.4.5.6 | 44 |
| x | 239.1.1.12 | 22 | 239.4.5.6 | 45 |
| x | 239.1.1.13 | 21 | 239.4.5.6 | 46 |
| x | 239.1.1.13 | 22 | 239.4.5.6 | 47 |
| x | 239.7.8.9 | 81 | 239.1.1.12 | 21 |
| x | 239.7.8.9 | 82 | 239.1.1.12 | 22 |
| x | 239.7.8.9 | 83 | 239.1.1.13 | 21 |
| x | 239.7.8.9 | 84 | 239.1.1.13 | 22 |

Comment: More details needed of the problem, as has stated two solutions do not match criteria that are not in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Any variation on "column1 and column2 and ..." indicates a schema design problem. Lists in SQL are represented by join tables.

Also note that Postgres has [network address types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-net-types.html).

```
create table devices (
    id serial primary key
);

create table device_addresses (
    device_id int not null references devices(id),
    ip inet not null,
    port integer not null check(port > 0),

    unique(ip, port)
);
```

With this design, a device can have as many addresses as it wants, and you can avoid duplicate addresses.

You can pull add the addresses for a single device together by grouping by the device id and using [`string_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) to aggregate all the addresses.

```
select
  name,
  string_agg(ip || ':' || port, ', ') as addresses
from devices d
left join device_addresses da on d.id = da.device_id
group by d.id
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/nGK8h_8F)

Comment: That just moves the issue - not resolving it.  I would still need my main table to have 2 devices A and B that must be unique across both columns

Comment: @BruceHartweg The unique constraint on the device_addresses appears to solve your problem, addresses are unique across devices. Why do the device addresses need to be in the same table as the devices?

Comment: The addresses don’t, but my main table would have two “devices” A and B. And they would need to be unique independently across all rows as well, so again, unique(A) and unique(B) but also no A can be same as any B and vice versa. Maybe ther is no constraint that can do this and I need to solve with an insert trigger that checks opposite columns

Comment: @BruceHartweg Myabe I don't understand the question. From your list of exclusions in your question, it seems like you just want unique addresses regardless of device or whether it's the first or second address for a device. The schema in this answer satisfies that, it will exclude all the devices in your list because they use an existing address. Could you give a concrete example where it doesn't do what you want?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to restructure your table

```
Create table config (
                Id serial NOT NULL,
                IP text,
                Port integer,
                OtherConfigID integer NULL)
```

And that way you can put a unique constraint on IP & Port.

OtherPortID has to be NULL so you can insert the first port details when you don't have the ID of the second port config, but practically you will always populate it.

Comment: not an option., The table contains many more columns and already contains a reference to itself for other reasons,

Comment: @BruceHartweg  Then you need to add those details to your question.